# ArcGIS Pro Modelbuilder - How to specify which map with the "add to display" option

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, arcgis-online

I'm utilizing a model to update feature layers in AGOL.

The model I have used follows this blog post: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/publish-and-overwrite-web-layers-in-modelbuilder/

I need to go this route, and I understand other options exist.

The problem:

I have a layer which first needs to be copied out of the master geodatabase and joined to another table before this model runs. With this model, each feature class needs to have it's own map (there are multiple feature classes and maps within this ArcGIS Pro project). When I run a model to automate the Copy & Join, the feature class is removed from the map I placed it in. I can automatically add this feature class by clicking the "add to display" function in the model. However, this project has multiple maps within it's project.

How do I specify which Map the "add to display" function adds to?

Answer (score 1):

Modelbuilder adds outputs to the current, or previously/most recently active map.
If your workflow needs to target layers in separate maps, you can:

1. Hardcode the layers as variables
2. Use multiple submodels with "iterate layers", specify a different map for each and find a way to catch desired layers or
3. Python. Unless you can work with the above, this is likely your best/only option